# hls fails to play m3u8 playlist with videojs

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, video.js, m3u8

I created an hls stream from yuv frames with ffmpeg which appears to work just fine. It creates a playlist and updates that, and all .ts files as expected. However even videojs refuses to play it, and I really run out of ideas, probably missing the obvious?

First, the m3u8 list which is continuously updated:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:190
#EXTINF:2.000000,
test190.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
test191.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
test192.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
test193.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
test194.ts
```

Those .ts files exist and have sizes of approx 250 kBytes.
Then, I open this standard videojs html file (residing in the same directory):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>videojs-contrib-hls embed</title>

  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>VSTream</h1>

  <video-js id="my_video_1" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="test.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
  </video-js>
  
  <script src="video.min.js"></script>
  <script src="videojs-http-streaming.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I open this in Firefox (or Chrome, or Edge, none works) and use its debugger which in the console shows:

> VIDEOJS: WARN: A plugin named "reloadSourceOnError" already exists.
> You may want to avoid re-registering plugins! video.min.js:12:977
> Specified “type” attribute of “application/x-mpegURL” is not
> supported. Load of media resource test.m3u8 failed. vstream.html All
> candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused. vstream.html
> XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: file:///C:/test/test.m3u8
> Line Number 1, Column 1: 2 test.m3u8:1:1 MouseEvent.mozPressure is
> deprecated. Use PointerEvent.pressure instead. video.min.js:12:9031
> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE) Playback cannot continue. No
> available working or supported playlists.  Object { code: 3, message:
> "Playback cannot continue. No available working or supported
> playlists." } video.min.js:12:977

This doesn't make much sense to me. Why would it throw an XML parsing error for an m3u8 file? Of course, the MEDIA_ERR_DECODE points in some direction, but the same problem persists with fMP4 files.

The relevant ffmpeg c++ code (format is "hls" and formatContext works well in other scenarios, gop is 2):

```
    AVDictionary* options = 0;
    if (fragmented)
    {
        // type
        if (codecID == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
            av_dict_set (&options, "hls_segment_type", "fmp4", 0);
        else
            av_dict_set (&options, "hls_segment_type", "mpegts", 0);

        av_dict_set (&options, "hls_time", "2.0", 0);
        av_dict_set_int (&options, "hls_list_size", 5, 0);
        av_dict_set (&options, "hls_flags", "delete_segments", 0);
    }

    int ret = avformat_write_header (formatContext, &options);
```

...which returns success. Then writing frames

```
    int ret = avcodec_send_frame (videoStream->codecContext, frame);
    av_init_packet (avPacket);
    AVRational timeBase = videoStream->getTimeBase ();
    avPacket->stream_index = streams.indexOf (videoStream);
    ret = avcodec_receive_packet (videoStream->codecContext, avPacket);
    avPacket->duration = av_rescale_q (1, videoStream->codecContext->time_base, videoStream->getTimeBase ());
    pts += avPacket->duration;
    avPacket->pts = pts;
    avPacket->dts = pts;    //  AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame (formatContext, avPacket);
```

(videoStream here is an internal object representing the avstream).
I've omitted error checks for clarity. All return values show success.
Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: HI, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Figured out using ffmpeg debug, that the files to write failed to do so because they had been opened before. So make sure to close all files before starting to stream. Also enable ffmpeg debugging at least at warning level, it helped a lot with other issues too.